# How to get Label inside repeater not in itemdatabound

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I'm trying to get a label inside a repeater in a "for" loop, but I keep getting an error saying:

> "An exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative
>   and less than the size of the collection."

Here's my code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    Label AppAmmount = (Label)rpOffers.Items[i].FindControl("AppAmmount");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping `dt.Rows.Count` but you are accessing `rpOffers.Items`. It seems the `DataTable` contains more rows than the repeater.

But why not a simple `foreach`?

```
foreach(RepeaterItem item in rpOffers.Items)
{
    Label AppAmmount = (Label)item.FindControl("AppAmmount");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rpOffers.Items.Count` instead of `dt.Rows.Count`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < rpOffers.Items.Count; i++)
{
    Label AppAmmount = (Label)rpOffers.Items[i].FindControl("AppAmmount");
}
```